# SQL Server: Retrieve the Group By sum

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, group-by, sum

I'm stucked on this question for quite a while, and even though some people may have mentionned this problem in other situtations,

=> **is there a way to obtain the sum of the rows grouped by while using the GROUP BY clause in SQL Server ?**

My problem is the following: i have a table named OrderedProduct (which joins a table of Orders and a table Products if you can imagine) with two fields: **orderedProductId** and **axBatchNumber**.
I would like to retriev only the differents **axBatchNumber** and their sum on the same row

[image: Such as]

The result of the query should be like:

1. HC268136 | 2
2. HC304026 | 1
3. HC388941 | 3
4. 11C03312 | 4

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please include what you have tried.

Comment: `COUNT` <--- you're going to want to use that.

Comment: Your sample data and output is simply `SELECT axBatchNumber, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable GROUP BY axBatchNumber`  Is that all you are after? The wording of your question makes it seem like it should be more complex.

Comment: Sorry, my bad ! It was COUNT indeed who finally did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need a SUM or a COUNT?

Something like the following may answer to your question?

```
SELECT axBatchNumber, COUNT(*) AS CC
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY axBatchNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was finally the COUNT function that worked for what i wanted to do.